# Fonts slightly wider in OpenJDK vs OracleJDK

Tags: java

I'm noticing differences in font spacing using OpenJDK compared to OracleJDK. I've narrowed this down to the fonts. They are rendered by OpenJDK ever so slightly wider... Careful visual inspection of the screenshot above shows the character widths are identical, the only difference is the spacing. I also confirmed this with programmatic check of font metrics for all characters A-Za-z0-9.

[image: OpenJDK vs OracleJDK fonts]

e.g. the String "Dialog - plain" at 12pt is

- 125px wide in OpenJDK - my build of 8u131-b11
- 125px wide in OpenJDK - stock RPM from redhat disk - 1.8u45-b13
- 120px wide in OracleJDK - 8u131-b11 release from Oracle website

I've searched extensively for information on this and found various options including `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings`, `-Dswing.useSystemFontSettings`, `-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel` from [Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts). I've tried altering all of these but the results remain the same.

Further investigation has found `sun.font.FontScaler`, this uses different underlying fontscaler. This appears partially configurable in `sun.font.FontUtilities` which checks the system property for `-Dsun.java2d.font.scaler=t2k`, however setting this makes no difference.

My question: can `FreetypeFontScaler` be configured to behave in a similar or closer way to T2KFontScaler?

```
if (FontUtilities.isOpenJDK) {
      scalerClass = Class.forName("sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler");
} else {
      scalerClass = Class.forName("sun.font.T2KFontScaler");
}
```

This is the test program I've been using

```
public class FontTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.format("java.home=%s", System.getProperty("java.home")));

        String family = Font.DIALOG;
        int style = Font.PLAIN;
        describeFont(new Font(family, style, 12));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(new DemoPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static class DemoPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            String family = Font.DIALOG;
            int style = Font.PLAIN;
            Font font = new Font(family, style, 20);
            g.setFont(font);
            String str = family + " - " + name(font) + " ";
            Rectangle2D bounds = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(str, g);
            str += String.format("%f x %f", bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
            g.drawString(str, 10, 50);
        }

        private String name(Font font) {
            List<String> attrs = new ArrayList<>();
            if (font.isBold()) {
                attrs.add("bold");
            }
            if (font.isItalic()) {
                attrs.add("italic");
            }
            if (font.isPlain()) {
                attrs.add("plain");
            }
            return String.join(",", attrs);
        }
    }

    private static void describeFont(Font font) throws Exception {
        Method method = Font.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFont2D");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Font2D font2d = (Font2D) method.invoke(font);
        System.out.print(String.format("%s: ", font));
        describeFont2D(font2d);
    }

    private static void describeFont2D(Font2D font) {
        if (font instanceof CompositeFont) {
            CompositeFont cf = (CompositeFont) font;
            for (int i = 0; i < cf.getNumSlots(); i++) {
                PhysicalFont pf = cf.getSlotFont(i);
                describeFont2D(pf);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print(String.format("-> %s \n", font));
        }
    }
}
```

Yet more investigation has traced this though to `sun.font.FontStrike.getGlyphMetrics(int)` returning different results. For a glyph-id 39 ("D") the advance X value is returned as 14.0px using Oracle JDK (via T2KFontScaler) but 15.0px using OpenJDK (via FreetypeFontScaler)

To figure which is "correct" I used the [fontbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) Java parser to extract the advance X value for Glyph-ID 39 from the HMTX table within the TTF file LiberationSans-Regular.ttf. The value is 1479 font design units - which maps to 14.44px at 20pt font size.

There is no difference for the next character "i" - glyph-id 76. This is 4.44 according to fontbox, and returned as 4 by both T2KScaler and FreetypeScaler

I've further narrowed this down to the rounding / calculation used when standard "non-fractional" metrics are used. If fractional metrics are enabled then both Oracle and Open JDKs behave identically, although the widths are still slighly smaller than the Oracle non-fractional case.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
```

Update - Jan 2020
 * In Java 11 there is new option which may be related - see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217731

```
FREETYPE_PROPERTIES=truetype:interpreter-version=35
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible as font rendering libraries are different in Oracle Java and most OpenJDK builds - http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2017-November/004621.html

Comment: Most probably not the case: but as DIALOG is a logical font, you might better check a specific non-JDK font first, or explore whether the fonts are indeed the same.

Comment: It can be even worse than "slightly wider". I have a "6" that look looks awfully lot like an "8". +1 from me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Further investigation has found sun.font.FontScaler, this uses different underlying fontscaler. This appears partially configurable in sun.font.FontUtilities which checks the system property for -Dsun.java2d.font.scaler=t2k, however setting this makes no difference.

You're correct in that the underlying font scaler is different between Oracle and OpenJDK - unfortunately however, this is hard coded and not configurable.

The relevant code is in [FontScaler:97](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/font/FontScaler.java):

```
if (FontUtilities.isOpenJDK) {
    scalerClass = Class.forName("sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler");
} else {
    scalerClass = Class.forName("sun.font.T2KFontScaler");
}
```

And the `isOpenJDK` flag? It's set by [FontUtilities:125](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/font/FontUtilities.java):

```
File lucidaFile = new File(jreFontDirName + File.separator + LUCIDA_FILE_NAME);
isOpenJDK = !lucidaFile.exists();
```

And that constant:

```
static final String LUCIDA_FILE_NAME = "LucidaSansRegular.ttf";
```

Unless I've missed something in those source files, there's no other configuration flag or any other condition that will change that scaler class being used.

So the only vaguely sensible way of doing this (I'm excluding horrible classloader / reflection hacks here) is to add that Lucida file in place. Unfortunately though in most scenarios I can think of (assuming you're not distributing the JRE along with the package) this isn't really going to be a viable solution either.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I investigated what you suggest earlier - placing the Lucida fonts to make OpenJDK "look" like Oracle JDK, unfortunately T2KFontScaler is backed by a native libt2k.so which is not present. This is closed source and I'm wary of the licensing implications of just copying the one from Oracle distro....

Comment: @Adam Yes, that's correct - I actually had the same (or similar) issue reported against something i developed a while back, and came to the same conclusion (that unless I wanted potential legal trouble, there was no way I could really just copy those files across and be done with it.) I don't think there's an easy solution to this, unfortunately.

Comment: There is one solution which I've not yet explored.... as my investitgation shows the differences are down to the "advance X" values being intrepreted differently from the TTF file... I could create a new set of manipulated TTF files that only OpenJDK uses with a "fudge factor" applied to the the "advance X" such that rendered output is loosely the same -- this may seem insane but the cost compared to tweaking layouts of 100+ legacy UI screens would be a lot less :)

Comment: @Adam It does indeed seem insane, but I'm fully appreciative that maintaining legacy software often mandates an insane approach from time to time!

Comment: @Adam Out of interest, did you ever implement the new set of "fudged" TTF files? Curious as to whether that helped!