# Float font size is not working in OpenJDK

Tags: java, fonts, awt, fontmetrics

Float font size is not working in OpenJDK.
Seems that the font size is rounded off while calculating string bounds 
e.g. 11.4 -> 11 & 11.5 -> 12
However in oracle jdk its working perfectly.

Any idea how to resolve this in OpenJDK 8?

**Program:**

```
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

    public class TestFont {
        public static void main(String  []args){
            FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
            Font font = new Font("Courier New",0,(int)11.5);
            font = font.deriveFont(11.5f);
            Rectangle2D bound = font.getStringBounds("PAGE",0,4, frc);
            System.out.println("Char width:"+ bound.getWidth() / 4);
            Font2D font2D = FontUtilities.getFont2D(font);
            System.out.println("Font2D:" + font2D.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Results:**

```
OpenJDK 7,8,9:
Char width:7.201171875
Font2D:** TrueType Font: Family=Courier New Name=Courier New style=0 fileName=C:\windows\Fonts\cour.ttf

Oracle JDK 8:
Char width:6.901123046875
Font2D:** TrueType Font: Family=Courier New Name=Courier New style=0 fileName=C:\windows\Fonts\cour.ttf
```

Comment: can you display in each case the full font definition : open jdk and oracle doesn't have the same font available so if it doesn' t found your font jdk will use the default one that can be completely different.

Comment: I added font info in results.
Both are using same font file.

while debugging I noticed that both jdk using different font scaler
Oracle JDK : T2KFontScaler
Open JDK: FreetypeFontScaler
I am not sure if this will impact

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fonts slightly wider in OpenJDK vs OracleJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884684/fonts-slightly-wider-in-openjdk-vs-oraclejdk)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did a lot of tests also with Oracle JDK(jdk-8, jdk-8u5, jdk-8u102, jdk-8u201) and the same, the float sizes are not considered. Every value less than 11.5 is rounded to 11 and bigger than 11.5 is rounded to 12. I used to write text with Graphics2D. Does anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That 's what i was thinking ^^. here is a topic related to your issue :

[Fonts slightly wider in OpenJDK vs OracleJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884684/fonts-slightly-wider-in-openjdk-vs-oraclejdk)